# How to Find Matrix Exponential

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a 2x2 matrix A with rows (1 0) and (1 1).  How can I find their matrix exponential, e^A ?

I understand I need to plug it into the Taylor series but I'm lost at how to solve the series here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note**.  I shall do this with the series because that's what you asked for.  There are easier methods which I expect you will learn later.

We have $A=I+N$ where
$$N=\pmatrix{0&0\cr1&0\cr}\ .$$
It is easy to calculate that $N^2=0$.  Also, $I$ and $N$ commute, so we can use the binomial theorem:
$$A^k=(I+N)^k=I^k+kI^{k-1}N+\binom k2 I^{k-2}N^2+\cdots=I+kN\ .$$
So by using the series,
$$\eqalign{e^A
  &=I+\frac1{1!}A+\frac1{2!}A^2+\frac1{3!}A^3+\cdots\cr
  &=I+\frac1{1!}(I+N)+\frac1{2!}(I+2N)+\frac1{3!}(I+3N)+\cdots\cr
  &=xI+yN\ ,\cr}$$
where
$$x=1+\frac1{1!}+\frac1{2!}+\frac1{3!}+\cdots=e$$
and
$$y=\frac1{1!}+\frac2{2!}+\frac3{3!}+\cdots=1+\frac1{1!}+\frac1{2!}+\cdots=e
  \ .$$
Hence,
$$e^A=eI+eN=eA\ .$$

Comment: Wow thank you very much. That really made things simpler.